# How to load fastify-env environments synchronously?

Tags: fastify

I'm working on fastify microservice and would like to use the fastify-env library to validate my env inputs and provide defaults throughout the whole app.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()
fastify.register(require('fastify-env'), {
  schema: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      PORT: { type: 'string', default: 3000 }
    }
  }
})
console.log(fastify.config) // undefined

const start = async opts => {
  try {
    console.log('config', fastify.config) // config undefined
    await fastify.listen(3000, '::')
    console.log('after', fastify.config)  // after { PORT: '3000' }

  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start()
```

How can I use the `fastify.config` object before the server starts?

Comment: Did you get your answer for this? Are you still using fastify-env?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fastify.register` loads plugins asynchronously AFAIK. If you'd like to immediately use things from a specific plugin use:

```
fastify
    .register(plugin)
    .after(() => {
        // This particular plugin is ready!
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ready()` https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Server/#ready to wait for all plugins to be loaded. Then call `listen()` with your config variable.

```
try {
    await fastify.ready(); // will load all plugins
    await fastify.listen(...);
} catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastify concept is built like you add dependencies via register. And then everything will be loaded when we run fastify instance via **ready** method or **listen**:
https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#ready

```
async function bootstrap() {
   // ------- Compile time in fastify lifecycle ----------
   const serverInstance = require('fastify')();

   serverInstance.register(envPlugin); // Register but not run the plugin at this moment.

   console.log(serverInstance.config); // When you try to access config, there is no config added into fastify container
   // ------- End Compile time in fastify lifecycle----------

   // ------- Run time -> Loading plugins ----------
   try {
     await serverInstance.ready(); // This will wait all the plugins loaded into fastify container

     console.log(serverInstance.config); // Now everything is loaded, log will contains values
   }
}

bootstrap();
```